# Async function is not returning expected data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, firebase-authentication

I am trying to verify phone number using firebase. But getting unexpected result from async function. Here is my code :

```
  bool isVerificationSuccess = false;

  Future<bool> verifyUserPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
      verificationCompleted: (credential) => verificationComplete(credential),
      verificationFailed: (authException) => verificationFailed(authException),
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) =>
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout(verificationId),
      codeSent: (verificationId, [code]) => smsCodeSent(verificationId, [code]),
    );
    print("Status from service : $isVerificationSuccess");
    return isVerificationSuccess;
  }

  verificationComplete(AuthCredential credential) async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

    user.linkWithCredential(credential).then((_) {
      print("User Successfully Linked");
      isVerificationSuccess = true;
    }).catchError((e) {
      print("Linking Error : ${e.toString()}");
    });
  }
```

Here is the output :

```
 Status from service : false
 User Successfully Linked
```

So here `verifyUserPhoneNumber` function returns even before the completion of `FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber()`, so its not returning expected data (always `false`) even when the verification is successful. Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the function call in this line:

```dart
verificationCompleted: (credential) => verificationComplete(credential),
```

is not awaited, even though the function itself is asynchronous. So what happens is:

1. `verifyUserPhoneNumber` is called from somewhere
2. `FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber` is awaited
3. Within this call, `verificationComplete(credential)` is called and, because it itself contains an await statement, it will be queued up by the Dart event loop. So whatever happens after `FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();` is delayed!
4. `verifyUserPhoneNumber` now continues executing and returns `false`.
5. After a value has already been returned, it is now `verificationComplete`'s turn to process. It will change the boolean value, and then exit.

My recommendation here is not to use a global variable, but instead, for example, call `verificationComplete` *after* `FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber` has already fully finished processing and returned.

Edit: This is how you could theoretically fix the issue, though it is not particularly pretty I do admit:

```dart
  Future<bool> verifyUserPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) async {
    final completer = Completer<AuthCredential>();
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
      verificationCompleted: completer.complete,
      verificationFailed: completer.completeError,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) =>
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout(verificationId),
      codeSent: (verificationId, [code]) => smsCodeSent(verificationId, [code]),
    );
    try {
      final credential = await completer.future;
      return await verificationComplete(credential);
    } catch (e) {
      verificationFailed(e);
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> verificationComplete(AuthCredential credential) async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    try {
      await user.linkWithCredential(credential);
      print("User Successfully Linked");
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Linking Error : ${e.toString()}");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Calling verificationComplete requires credential. So how can I get credential after the completion of FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber. The whole thing is really confusing!

Comment: I added an example of what you could do.

Comment: Tried it. But no change.

Comment: Okay I may have misunderstood the situation. The documentation isn't entirely clear about this, but `FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber` might be exiting before calling any of the callbacks. Please try my new example.

Comment: In vain, your solutions not even do the main task (number verification).

Answer (score 1):

if u can place in `isVerificationSuccess = true;` inside function `verificationComplete(credential)` then u might get `true` value

Comment: Yeah, though its already in verificationComplete() function, may be the value need to be changed outside of then() block. +1 for that.

Comment: But why verifyUserPhoneNumber() function returns value without waiting? It returns value before verificationComplete() completes.

Comment: i think it has something to do with streams : If successful, it also signs the user in into the app and updates the [onAuthStateChanged] stream.

Comment: if u can somehow implement onAuthStateChanged in your code then it can work

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

> So here verifyUserPhoneNumber function returns even before the
>   completion of FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(), so its not
>   returning expected data (always false) even when the verification is
>   successful. Whats wrong here?

`FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber` uses a method channel `plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth` and calls a native method for authentication.

It uses the call back specified in the argument `verificationCompleted` once verification completes. However, from the function definitions, it seems that `FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber` expects a type `void Function(AuthCredential)`. However, you provide `Future<void> Function(AuthCredential)`

> Whats wrong here?

It seems that what is wrong is to expect that `FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber` will wait for an async call back `Future<void> Function(AuthCredential)` to complete when it expects a `void Function (AuthCredential)`.

So it just calls your `verificationComplete(AuthCredential credential) async` implementation which returns a `Future<void>`. At this moment, `FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber` is complete and the control moves ahead to `print` and `return isVerificationSuccess` which is still `false` as the future returned by `verificationComplete(AuthCredential credential) async` is not resolved yet.

So,

1. Return a `Future<void>` from `verifyUserPhoneNumber`
2. Update the App's state using a `setState` inside `verificationComplete` after you assign `isVerificationSuccess = true;` to rebuild your app after a successful verification